# Split the row in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Here i have row

```
row = "2016-07-25 00:00:00 UTC,237504,dsfdf,DM12,\"BPM , Fully Auto\""
```

i want to split this with `,`

```
row = row.split(",")
```

I am getting this

```
["2016-07-25 00:00:00 UTC", "237504", "dsfdf", "DM12", \"BPM ", " Fully Auto\""]
```

Is there a way to get this

```
["2016-07-25 00:00:00 UTC", "237504", "dsfdf", "DM12", "\"BPM , Fully Auto\""]
```

> We need to distinguish by "\"BPM , Fully Auto\""
>
> I need to do something here which does not split with comma if we
>   have enclosed this with `\" \"`

Comment: Where does that row come from? maybe there's a better way of doing this whole thing than splitting yourself to death.

Comment: so, this is constant? `"\"BPM , Fully Auto\""`?

Comment: This is string but inside `\" \"` comma needs to eliminate

Comment: eliminate as in? if you don't need comma between `BPM` and `Fully Auto`, you can `gsub(',', '')`

Comment: gsub  cant work, it remove other `,` also

Comment: you should probably try out some `regex` for that as regex can also be passed to `split`, or @Danny's solution sounds good to me.

Comment: Thanks @Md.FarhanMemon , dannys code works,

Comment: cool, and downvotes are probably cuz you failed to explain the requirement well in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the row come from a csv file?
Maybe you could use:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.parse_line(row)
# => ["2016-07-25 00:00:00 UTC", "237504", "dsfdf", "DM12", "\"BPM , Fully Auto\""]
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It's by far the easiest and most robust answer.

Answer (score 3):

[`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split) takes a second argument to limit the splits:

```
row.split(",", 4)
# => ["2016-07-25 00:00:00 UTC", "237504", "dsfdf", "DM12", "\"\"\"BPM , Fully Auto\"\"\""]
```

Comment: place can be changed

Comment: @VishwasNahar What do you mean by "place can be changed"?

Comment: This can also possible more numbers of columns here

Comment: like this ["2016-07-25 00:00:00 UTC", "237504", "dsfdf", "237504", "dsfdf"", "237504", "dsfdf"", "237504", "dsfdf" , "DM12", "\"\"\"BPM , Fully Auto\"\"\""]

Comment: It only works if the escaped commas are inside the last cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could also split, slice and join the requisite sections:

```
row = row.split(",")
row = row[0..-3] + [row[-2..-1].join(", ")]
```